# mysql executing query low performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to optimise my below SQL queries, target is to get results within 3-4 seconds.

```
select(
    ((select data from t_sayac_degerler where id = (select max(id) from t_sayac_degerler where adres = '1.8.0'  and tarih between '2016.02.15 11:00' and '2016.02.16 17:13')) 
    - 
    (select data from t_sayac_degerler where id = (select min(id) from t_sayac_degerler where adres = '1.8.0' and tarih between '2016.02.15 11:00' and '2016.02.16 17:13')))
    *
    (select multiplier from t_sayac where s_id = ((select s_id from t_sayac_degerler where id = (select max(id) from t_sayac_degerler where adres = '1.8.0' and tarih between '2016.02.15 11:00' and '2016.02.16 17:13'))))
    ) 
    as value
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you describe in words what this query should calculate?

Comment: 3 - 4 second return data.

Comment: That's not what he was asking.  He wants to know what this query is actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just curious if this would improve your performance, By removing the nested Select statements I am removing the nested loops. I have assumed that the id values are int:

```
DECLARE @MaxID int, @MinID int, @s_id int;


SELECT  @MaxID=max(id) , @MinID = min(id) 
FROM       t_sayac_degerler 
WHERE   adres = '1.8.0' and tarih between '2016.02.15 11:00' and '2016.02.16 17:13';

SELECT @s_id=s_id 
FROM   t_sayac_degerler 
WHERE  id = @MaxID


SELECT(
    (
      (SELECT data 
       FROM   t_sayac_degerler 
       WHERE  id = @MaxID) 
       - 
      (SELECT data 
       FROM   t_sayac_degerler 
       WHERE  id = @MinID)
    )
    *
    (SELECT multiplier 
    FROM   t_sayac 
    WHERE  s_id = @s_id
    )
) 
as value
```

Comment: Thanks Kamran Farzami